# Three-pass Protocol in CryptoJS and OpenSSL

Tags: javascript, encryption, openssl, cryptojs

I am looking to do a three-pass exchange with CryptoJS (client) and OpenSSL (server). I can not find any examples on how to do this, could any one pint me in the right directions. I am looking to do the following:

1. Server sends client a string encrypted with a randomly generated key.
2. Client encrypts the string with another key, and sends it back to the server
3. Server decrypts the string using server's key from step 1 and sends it back to the client
4. Client decrypts the string with client's key from step 2. Client now has original string from the server.

This is for a small app I am making. I have used CryptoJS before, but I never had to do the three-pass before, and an example to work from would be very helpful. Thank you for any help.

Comment: I am not able to understand that how the client will get original string. Can you explain and if possible using some mathematics?

Comment: It's a standard three-pass asymmetric key system. You can lookup more information about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography. It's a pretty common system, though I never had to implement one my self. It requires a commutative cipher. This means that you can encrypt a string with key1 and then key2. To decrypt it, you need to use both keys, but the order does not matter, this is what makes it commutative.

Comment: Okay. If it is commutative then it is understandable. It is not mentioned in the question, therefore got this doubt.

Comment: What is the problem you faced so far?

Comment: I just want to see if anyone has done it before in JS, and see an example. That's all.